# What is a simple way to set up an on click handler for 4 quiz answer buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 beautiful buttons of class `.button` in css. Is there a simple way (presumably `jQuery` is the standard method) to put a event listener on these buttons.

Obviously the code will need to record which button was clicked, because only one of them has the right answer. The code below doesn't make that distinction, as `button` is a class not an ID. I suspect I will have to create four separate button IDs but that will multiply my css code by four.

I have been searching for a jQuery solution for a few days but not able to get any code to suit my particular situation.

This is the first time I have used jQuery, so if I have blundered, please don't be too harsh! I will greatly appreciate any knowledgeable contribution to solve this puzzle.

Here is the code from where the answers get sorted and displayed:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:button").click(function() {
    alert('a button was clicked.')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>What is this?</b></p>
<div>
  <input type="button" class="button">
  <input type="button" class="button">
  <input type="button" class="button">
  <input type="button" class="button">
</div>
```

Comment: If you add an `id` to each `button`s, you don't need to make css to each button. Your class will still work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` to find which button was clicked as follow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:button").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value') + " button was clicked.")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>What is this?</b></p>
<div>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="First">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Second">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Third">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Fourth">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bhuwan.  I used your concept of adding the value to the input line and it has helped.   How would you suggest making the program pause and wait for the user to click on the button?  Currently it's running through a do...while loop in PHP.

Comment: @Bose You don't need to run a loop in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it with a `for` loop.

**javascript file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $buttons = $('.control-panel input:button');

  for (var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; i++) {
    $($buttons[i]).click((button) => {
      alert(button.target.value);
    });
  }
});
```

**html file**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>What is this?</b></p>
<div class="control-panel">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 1">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 2">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 3">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Button 4">
</div>
```

I added a `value` attribute to your inputs (which you're using as the buttons) to differentiate them.

Also, added a `.control-panel` class to the parent element so you can target only the buttons that are within this `<div>` without affecting other buttons on the page (it wouldn't matter if you didn't have any other `input` buttons on the page).

The idea here is to use the jQuery selector `$('.control-panel input:button');` to get an array of the button nodes, then loop through them one by one and attach an event listener to them.

Note that `button` is the parameter that the `.click(button)` function will receive, and it refers to the HTML element node itself - that's why you'll need to use `button.target.value` to retrieve its value, which would be "Button 1" or "Button 4" depending on which button you click.